# notifyDataSetChanged() not updating listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm updating my listview from my background method:

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                BaseAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                if(getListView().getAdapter() == null){ //Adapter not set yet.
                     setListAdapter(adapter);
                     Log.v("ha", "bla");
                }
                else
                { //Already has an adapter
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```

This code is executed:
-on first load 
-on scroll to load more content, where I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, but without success.

How can I update my code so I can use notifydatasetchanged and add the new data to the current data.

My whole code: http://pastebin.com/cWmday3i Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: You keep creating new adapter every time. You are calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on old adapter not newly created adapter which you don't even set.

Answer (score 2):

the way you wrote your code you should always call `setListAdapter`, because every time the runnable inside runOnUiThread is executed, you create a new Adapter, probably with a new data set. The only difference between `notifyDataSetChanged` and `NotifyDataSetChanged` is that the second one does not belong to the Android's API

Comment: If I use 'setListAdapter' the list will "scroll" back to the top, so do you have any suggestion how I could use notifyDataSetChanged or declare a global adapter and add the data to it.

Comment: you can try with an ArrayAdapter. It has a method called add, which you can use to update the content of current dataset.

Comment: Then would I have to "convert" my BaseAdapter to an ArrayAdapter? And store the ArrayAdapter after I have created it so I can add data to it

Comment: surely you have to change from SimpleAdapter to ArrayAdapter, but you can avoid to take it as member of your class

Answer (score 1):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` won't do anything if you don't first change the data. In your else block, you need to transfer your JSON results to the existing adapter before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Also, your code above the if block should be moved inside the if block, since it is unused outside of the if block. That ambiguity might have led to your oversight.

Comment: If I move the code above the If block to the If block, then I should transfer the new JSON results to the adapter at the else "block"

Comment: Actually, I looked at your complete code and see that you are directly changing the `productslist` object without creating a new one, so you are doing it correctly, although it still makes sense to move that adapter initialization inside the if block so you aren't needlessly creating it over and over.

Comment: Back to your original question then...was I incorrect to assume that your problem is that the list doesn't change at all?

Comment: No, You was correct at that part, the list does not change at all.

Answer (score -1):

Put below line out side runOnUiThread

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: If adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); would have effect (which it doesn't because there is nothing to update), then you would still be able to  update inside the UI thread

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will work.

> `getListView().getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`